# Запись результатов sql-запроса в файл в bash'е

Tags: sql, postgresql, bash

Как записать каждую запись результата sql-запроса в файл через пробел в bash'е? Как записать каждую запись результата sql-запроса в файл на отдельной строке в bash'е?

Comment: никогда не работал с постгресом но уверен что awk, sed + перенаправление вывода + xargs вам помогут

Answer (score 2):

```
psql dbname -c 'select * from test1' > file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "SELECT * FROM table" | psql -Uuser -Wpassword dbname > file
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql -h host -u user -e "SELECT account, shell FROM passwd" -ss namedb > shells.txt

[источник](http://oooportal.ru/?cat=article&id=1282)